# How to unpack and rebuild RPM packages on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm

How would I unpack and rebuild an RPM package on Fedora?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to ask this on serverfault, but to answer it quickly:

1. Download the source rpm (`.SRPM`), not the normal rpm.
2. Create an `.rpmmacros` file in your home directory and put this in it:

   ```
   _topdir /home/${USER}/rpmbuild
   %_signature gpg
   %packager Your Name <<your.name@mail.com>>
   %_gpg_name Your Name <<your.name@mail.com>>
   %_tmppath /tmp
   ```
3. Create an rpmbuild directory structure in your home directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{SPECS,SOURCES,RPMS,SRPMS,BUILD}
   ```
4. Install the source rpm.
5. Edit the specfile in `~/rpmbuid/SPECS`.
6. Run `rpmbuild -bb ${your_specfile}` to build a binary rpm from the contents of the source rpm.